# Encryption for Security purposes in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, security, laravel, encryption

i am using angular and trying to figure out how to encrypt and decrypt my messages using angular to avoid any kind of security issues in my application.i am using laravel for api development. I have quite a lot RnD on figuring out that how i can achieve it but unable to find any appropriate solution for it..can any one share his thoughts???thanks in advance..

Comment: What is it you want to secure? SSL/TLS exists for transparent transport security

Comment: There are many different types of encryption. Some are better than others for specific system architectures and some are not even applicable. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to implement SHA-256 but issue is it does not have decryption function..how i can achieve that???i want to encrypt a message using my own key..how i can achieve that???